# Unable to load images to personal github page

Tags: git, github-pages

I created a personal website using github.io (https://yjkimnada.github.io/) with one of my repositories (https://github.com/yjkimnada/yjkimnada.github.io). However, the images on the page are not loading. Specifically, these images are found in the "/images" folder and are called upon by the markdown files in the "/_posts" folder.

I searched and tried various solutions such as removing the underscore from folder names, adding ".." to the image paths (making them relative), etc. None have seemed to work. Would anyone be able to pinpoint where I went wrong?

Comment: If you check the url of those images you'll see that your image goes to https://yjkimnada.github.io/tn../images/synthetic_lethality.png
while the actual url to the img is https://yjkimnada.github.io/images/synthetic_lethality.png without that "tn..." in the middle so check how is your img url created

Comment: Thank you indeed. this fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In [yjkimnada.github.io/_layouts/default.html](https://github.com/yjkimnada/yjkimnada.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html#L65), you can find lines like this:

```
          <img src="/tn{{post.image}}" alt="project image" style="width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100%;" />
```

You should replace the `"/tn{{post.image}}`(...) by `/{{post.image}}`(...). You should afterwards also remove the `..` in
[yjkimnada.github.io/_posts/](https://github.com/yjkimnada/yjkimnada.github.io/tree/master/_posts).

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the issue!

Comment: @NapoleonBonaparte Then, you can accept the answer.